# Imageview with multiple adjacent TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create an android layout where I have an imageview along with a two column textview directly to the right of it all within a scrollview.

Think like a users profile picture and basic information layout.

I've created a wireframe of what I am trying to achieve, unfortunately I just can't seem to get the layout of the imageview - textview - textview correct.

Everything else I have done.

[image]

EDIT
This is what I have tried without an luck:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weight="0.4"
            android:src="@drawable/profileImg" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:weight="0.6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:weight="0.25">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="User ID"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pUID"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="pUID"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:weight="0.25">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="Full Name"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="fName"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:weight="0.25">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="Age"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pAge"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="pAge"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:weight="0.25">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="Date of Birth"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pDOB"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:text="pDOB"
                    android:textColor="#fff" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Show your xml code.

Comment: Show something... post your XML file or something...

Comment: @Aspicas I have added some axml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the next `XML file`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="none">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

                <TextView
                    android:text="TextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textView48"
                    android:textSize="24sp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:weight="0.6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.30">

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:weight="0.4"
                        android:src="@drawable/profileImg"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:weight="0.25"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="0.70">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:weight="0.25"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:text="TextView"
                                android:textColor="#000"
                                android:textSize="24sp"/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:weight="0.25"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:textSize="24sp"
                                android:text="TextView"
                                android:textColor="#000" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:weight="0.25"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:textSize="24sp"
                                android:text="TextView"
                                android:textColor="#000" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="1">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:weight="0.25"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:text="TextView"
                                android:textColor="#000"
                                android:textSize="24sp"/>
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:weight="0.25"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:textSize="24sp"
                                android:text="TextView"
                                android:textColor="#000" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:weight="0.25"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp">
                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:textSize="24sp"
                                android:text="TextView"
                                android:textColor="#000" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/textView83"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:textSize="18sp"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TextViewb"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="24sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TextViewc"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TextViewd"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="24sp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="TextViewe"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:textSize="24sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Output**

[image: one]

Comment: This is a pretty good working example. Is there a way to pre-define the imageview size? Looks like the size is currently based on the image.

Comment: mmm it should adapt to all images...you can change values by wrap_content or match_parent on image height/width attributes, or change `layout_weight` on the above Linear_layout

Answer (score 0):

`RelativeLayout` with an `ImageView` and 2 `LinearLayout`. The `LinearLayouts` will contain the `TextViews`.

The `ImageView` will be `allignParentLeft` and the other two layouts will have weights of 1 and layout to the left of the image view.